# Why do we need readlines() when we can iterate over the file handle itself?

Tags: python

In Python, after

```
fh = open('file.txt')
```

one may do the following to iterate over lines:

```
for l in fh:
    pass
```

Then why do we have `fh.readlines()`?

Comment: learning curve? in other words, transition from languages that are so pythonesque?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would imagine that it's from before files were iterators and is maintained for backwards compatibility. Even for a one-liner, it's <strike>totally</strike><sup>1</sup> fairly redundant as `list(fh)` will do the same thing in a more intuitive way. That also gives you the freedom to do `set(fh)`, `tuple(fh)`, etc.

<sup>1</sup> See [John La Rooy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933223/in-python-why-do-we-need-readlines-when-we-can-iterate-over-the-file-handle-it/3933557#3933557).

Comment: +1 Good point on `collection_constructor(fh)`. I must admit, it never occured to me.

Comment: When I was beginning with Python I used to `list(fh)` before I realized it was redundant. Are you sure it is for backward compatibility? I mean they did break a lot of that with Python 3, so why not clean this up too!

Comment: @Ashish, They really didn't break that much and no I'm not sure it's for backwards compatibility. I started programming python when 2.6 was not quite fairly new so I'm something of a noob. I've never even written code for 2.5 for instance so I don't know the history at all.

Comment: +1, gnibbler made a good point like you pointed out. which was in fact first pointed out in one of the comments by someone else.

Answer (score 16):

Mostly it is there for backward compatibility. readlines was there way before file objects were iterable

Using readlines with the size argument is also one of the fastest ways to read from files because it reads a bunch of data in one hit, but doesn't need to allocate memory for the entire file all at once

Answer (score 1):

`readlines()` returns a list of lines, which you may want if you don't plan on iterating through each line.

Comment: @MattH, note that the size is a hint, and more or less lines may be returned

Comment: @MattH: That makes it not redundant. Could you post it as an answer? That way it will help readers spot your point clearly. :)

Comment: @Ashish, posting that as an answer now would be redundant. Let Mr Gnibbler take the points.