# Finding a Word in a File

Tags: python, file-handling

I'm trying to read from a file 'input.txt', one line at a time, numbering each line. I then need to check each line to see whether the letters in the line can be used to make the word 'aardvark'. Uppercase letters can be used as well and the letters can be spread throughout the line. The text file's contents are:

```
No aardv*rks here!

Only armadillos and anteaters.

Animals are run down: very awful road kill.

I prefer a quick guacamole made from avocados.
```

So line 3 and 4 only should return a positive, such as "Aardvark on line 3".

I've gotten this far - and I'm stuck!

```
file = open('input.txt').read().lower() 
listed = file.split('\n')  
for sentence in listed:
  a = sentence.count('a')
  r = sentence.count('r')
  d = sentence.count('d')
  v = sentence.count('v')
  k = sentence.count('k')
  if a==3 and r==2 and d==1 and v==1 and k==1:
    print('Aardvark on line '+listed[sentence])
```

Please understand that I'm working through beginner tutorials, so no wild and fancy functions that will blow my tiny, fragile mind, please!!

Many thanks in anticipation.

**EDIT**

This is the solution that finally worked. Many thanks for the contributions once again!

```
file = open('input.txt').read().lower() 
listed = file.split('\n')  
for index, sentence in enumerate(listed):
  a = sentence.count('a')
  r = sentence.count('r')
  d = sentence.count('d')
  v = sentence.count('v')
  k = sentence.count('k')
  if a>=3 and r>=2 and d>=1 and v>=1 and k>=1:
    print('Aardvark on line '+str(index+1))
```

Comment: You should use `>=` because you can get `'aardvark'` from `'aarrrrrddddvaaaarkkkk'`

Comment: Doh! Good spot! Right, got that bit working, just trying to get the number to print in the final line - my code is not doing it #error

Comment: @Mathmos, If you do: `for i, sentence in enumerate(listed):` you can use `i` as the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open('input.txt').read()` reads the entire content of the file into memory. Thus, if `input.txt` is a long enough file the computer will exhaust its available memory. Instead, try reading the lines one at a time using the file iterator, e.g.

```
for i,listed in enumerate(open('input.txt')):
    sentence = listed.lower()
    a = sentence.count('a')
    # ... etc.
```

See also [In Python, why do we need readlines() when we can iterate over the file handle itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933223/in-python-why-do-we-need-readlines-when-we-can-iterate-over-the-file-handle-i).

Comment: Good point! The tutorials mentioned something about that! It seems that I passed the assignment without triggering this issue but something to be aware of for much bigger files.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but for those undertaking this task through Grok the following code uses only what has been taught so far in the course. Hope you find it useful!

```
count = 0
with open('input.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    count += 1
    l = line.lower()
    a = l.count('a')
    d = l.count('d')
    k = l.count('k')
    r = l.count('r')
    v = l.count('v')
    if a >= 3 and d >= 1 and k >= 1 and r >=2 and v >=1:
      print('Aardvark on line', count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n, line in enumerate(open('input.txt')):
  letters = list('aardvark')
  for c in line.lower():
    if c in letters:
      letters.remove(c)
  if not letters:
    print('Aardvark on line', n + 1)
```

Comment: Please elaborate what this code will do and how this is helping the OP. Spend some time and have a look at [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).