# AWS Boto3 Error of Malformed InstanceID when using for loop

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Hi I am experiencing an error when using a for loop for inputting instance id. Below is my code along with the error.

The code is just putting all instance ids in a file which I use to in a for loop to get a describe-instances output.

The format seems fine and when I manually input the instance id it works just fine. Let me know

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import boto3
import csv

ec2_re = boto3.resource('ec2')
ids= [instance.id for instance in ec2_re.instances.all()]
with open('ids.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
    for id in ids:
        file_handler.write("'{}'\n".format(id))

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
INSTANCE_ID = open("ids.txt", "r")  #need to loop thru this
for x in INSTANCE_ID:
    result = []
    response = ec2.describe_instances(
        InstanceIds=[
            x
        ]).get('Reservations')
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./excel_new.py", line 17, in <module>
    x
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 514, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 934, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.Malformed) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: Invalid id: "'i-03b6908c79e0dd9dd'
```

Comment: Typo in the instance ID read from file. Appears to have quotes.

Comment: So if i cat the file it only has single quotes which is what is required for the boto3 describe instances command. I tried without and same error of malformed instance id. also checked that it is indeed class string

Comment: Yes, it's a string, but it's a malformed instance ID. Instance IDs don't contain quotes. You've included single quotes in the written instance IDs. Don't do that. Or, strip them upon reading. They're not required, and in fact are harmful. A correct instance ID is `i-03b6908c79e0dd9dd`, not `'i-03b6908c79e0dd9dd'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your instance IDs without extraneous quotes. For example:

```
file_handler.write("{}\n".format(id))
```

There is a secondary issue in how you are reading the text file later. You need to strip newlines from the lines of text containing the instance IDs. For example:

```
with open("ids.txt", "r") as fp:
    for id in [line.rstrip() for line in fp.readlines()]:
        print(id)
```

Here's a fuller example that both writes and then reads instance IDs:

```
ids = ["id-12345", "id-23456", "id-34567"]

with open("ids.txt", "w") as fp:
    for id in ids:
        fp.write(f"{id}\n")

with open("ids.txt", "r") as fp:
    for id in [line.rstrip() for line in fp.readlines()]:
        print(id)
```

Because file objects in Python are iterators, you could also use:

```
for id in [line.rstrip() for line in open("ids.txt", "r")]:
    print(id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried with readlines and again got the same error of malformed instance id. whether i remove the single quotes or not seems to have no change as well.

Comment: Print the `id` value. What does it look like? If it contains single quotes, then that's not what you want. Fix the writing code to not write quotes and then re-run that.

Comment: when i print the id value it comes as 
   i-03b6908c79e0dd9dd


now for context the original script when I manually input the value i do need single quotes around the instance id so that was why i had single quotes. Also with readline it looks like it adds a additional space between instance id . before method there wasnt a space between them

apologies on the format of my replies, this is my first time actually using stackoverflow myself

Comment: Updated answer to strip the newlines. Make sure your ids.txt file simply contains one line per instance ID, and the text of each line is something like `i-03b6908c79e0dd9dd` with no quotes.

Comment: Amazing that worked!! Just for future purpose why didnt it work originally without readlines? I am newer to python and would like to better understand it

Comment: Actually, the original iteration over the file would have worked fine if instead of `for x in INSTANCE_ID` you had used `for x in [line.rstrip() for line in INSTANCE_ID]` to strip the newlines. See related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933223/why-do-we-need-readlines-when-we-can-iterate-over-the-file-handle-itself).

Comment: I gave you bad info earlier about the file handle not being iterable. It is, so I updated my answer.